# Sort mapped list with Lodash on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reactjs, lodash

I have an array:

```
people = [
  {
    name: "Kyle",
    _id: "2"
  },
  {
    name: Susan,
    _id: "1"
  }
]
```

I have a mapped list as such:

```
return (
  <ul>
    {people.map( (person) => {
      return (
        <li>
          <span>{person.name}</span>
          <span>{person.id}</span>
        </li>
       )
    })}
  </ul>
)
```

This is all working well, but how can I sort them, say based on "name"? I tried to use the `[_.sortBy][1]` but couldn't figure out how it would fit to the context of React and map function.  Using lodash, or underscore's _.sortBy would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `_.sortBy` you can pass the name of the field that will be used for sorting your collection, read more about [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            people: _.sortBy([
                { name: "Kyle", _id: 2}, 
                { name: "Susan", _id: 1}
            ], '_id')
        }
    },

    sortBy(field) {
        this.setState({ 
            people: _.sortBy(this.state.people, field) 
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        var peopleList = this.state.people.map( (person, index) => {
            return (<li key={index}>
                <span>{person.name}</span>
                <span>{person.id}</span>
            </li>);        
        })

        return <div>
            <a onClick={this.sortBy.bind(this, '_id')}>Sort By Id</a> | 
            <a onClick={this.sortBy.bind(this, 'name')}>Sort By Name</a>
            <ul>{peopleList}</ul>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20013/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sortBy like this:

```
_.sortBy(<array name here>, '<key here>')
```

Try

```
return (
    <ul>
        {_.sortBy(people, 'name').map( (person) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <span>{person.name}</span>
                    <span>{person.id}</span>
                </li>
            )
        })}
    </ul>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it first

```
import sortBy from "lodash/sortBy";
```

And then you can use it like

```
const arr = [{id: 2}, {id: 0}];
sortBy(arr, "id");
```